# Restore deleted workflow in YouTrack

Tags: youtrack

I have been coding some workflows for the project and when we decided that we do not need some rule, I clicked on [image].

Apparently, Workflow is a name for group of modules, not each one individual module. And I was inside the editor, so I had no idea, that this could delete all my 4 weeks of work =(

Is there any way to restore the deleted workflow with rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have YouTrack on-premises, you should use Docker to restore version from backup and Export Workflows.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Back-Up-the-Database.html#restore-your-installation